# Develop android and iphone app

Tags: android, iphone

I'm gonna develop a small app both for android and Iphone. The app will contain a simple little online magazine. I have not done any app before. I work with developing Web pages in asp.net c# and I'm familiar with java. So I'm a beginner in terms of mobile apps, and now I'm wondering how to begin and where to find good information about basic app-development.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) so you can get higher quality answers to your questions.

Comment: The responses to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219377 might be of use to you.

Comment: I would evaluate both PhoneGap (aka Cordova) and Titanium Appcelerator.  IMHO...

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't building anything complex and just want to display something, a good solution might be [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). You can develop using HTML, CSS and Javascript and deploy to multiple platforms.

If you want to develop native applications, however, for Android, you can follow [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html) tutorials. He provides a set of tutorials starting from beginner level to intermediate.

Comment: +1 for Vogella. This is where I started with Android.

Comment: I started with Android on Android.  And I agree completely with you - PhoneGap (HTML5/CSS/Javascript) is a reasonable alternative to the "native" Android API (Java); and Vogella's tutorials are excellent.  I would also recommend this book: [Phone Gap Essentials, John M. Wargo](http://www.amazon.com/John-M.-Wargo/e/B002BLY6VU/)

Answer (score 1):

There are many routes you can go. I will try to list some below:

1. Java / Objective C. You will need to know how to program in each of these languages (java for droid and Obj C for iphone). Use the SDK for the respective platform.
2. Cross Platform mobile platform- You can use frameworks like Rhodes, Sensa touch, etc. This will let you write code one time and build the packages for android, iphone, and much more.
3. Web- You can write applications using web technologies like HTML5, CSS, Javascript, etc and there are tools to package them as Android / Iphone application. Otherwise, you can use a WebView in Android (which basically creates a browser-like experience in your application).

It is upto you to decide the best route to go. There are tons of information available online (stackoverflow, and Android/Iphone sdk websites).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take a look at http://developer.android.com/ for guidance in android development